# integrate javascript in jsp

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

How to convert this javascript

```js
<script>
window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"><\/script>')
</script>
```

in order to be accepted by a jsp file using `<c:url>` , I proceed in that way and it doesn't work

```js
 <script>
   window.jQuery || document.write('<script  src="<c:url value='js/vendor/jquery-1.10.1.min.js' />" ></script>')
</script>
```

Please help

Comment: Did you forget to escape `</script>` in second example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new script element with JavaScript, append it to the document body and wrap it in a function and call it like this:

```js
function importJQuery() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type="text/javascript";
    script.src= "js/vendor/jquery-1.10.1.min.js";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    alert("jQuery imported successfully");
}
window.jQuery || importJQuery();
```

This way if jQuery is not recognized it will be imported.

Comment: @SamiKobbi: How this answers question about `<c:url>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do following. Keep your js in top level dir of your application. 
Example:- yourapp\yourJSDir\yourJS.js

```
<script src="yourJSDir/yourJS.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create script object using `document.createElement`, then append script object in document head.

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
script.setAttribute("src", "js/vendor/jquery-1.10.1.min.js");

window.jQuery || document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: please avoid the use of `document.write()` , it's a bad parctice to use it.